# Resource not generating helper method for create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, routes

I have a model called package, which has a controller package created under a name space admin.

so my resource in my routes is declared as below

```
namespace :admin do
    resources :package
end
```

when I run `rake routes`

```
admin_package_index GET  /admin/package(.:format) admin/package#index
                    POST   /admin/package(.:format) admin/package#create
new_admin_package GET    /admin/package/new(.:format) admin/package#new
edit_admin_package GET    /admin/package/:id/edit(.:format) admin/package#edit
admin_package GET    /admin/package/:id(.:format)  admin/package#show
              PUT    /admin/package/:id(.:format)  admin/package#update
              DELETE /admin/package/:id(.:format)  admin/package#destroy
```

If you see there is no helper method generated for create, which should have been admin_packages_path

## controller

@newpackage = Package.new

## view.html.erb

```
form_for [:admin,@newpackage] do |f|
end
```

is reporting that it is not able to find the admin_packages_path. Can somebody please explain how should we declare this in routes to generate the proper helper method for create ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your routes are named incorrectly, you're pairing a plural (`resources`) with a singular (`:package`).

If you will be working with multiple packages, you should declare `resources :packages` - this will generate you correctly named routes for all seven RESTful actions (index, show, new, create, edit, update, destroy).

If you are only working with a single package, you will need to specify the URL as an option for your form manually, eg.

```
form_for [:admin, @newpackage], url: admin_package_path do |f|
```

Comment: I tried this before, but when I state the resource as plural

resources :packages it skips creating the index path

url: admin_package_path(@newpackage) generates an error that I no id  is present

Comment: That's because it would then be `index_packages_path(@new_package)`

Comment: the index path would just be `admin_packages_path`. No need to specify `index` or a package. `admin_package_path` is the show route, and you need to provide it a valid persisted package - if `@newpackage` is not saved, you cannot show it.

Answer (score 0):

You really need to changes the routes to following:

```
namespace :admin do
    resources :packages
end
```